# Apexcharts with custom tooltip with link is not possible to click

Tags: javascript, css, apexcharts

I'm trying to create a custom tooltip in apexCharts heatmap using the custom parameter to add code, in this case a specific link

```
    tooltip: {
            custom: function({ series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) {
              // code to return a string with a link
            }
    }
```

But if I want a link within the tooltip, how can I make tooltip stick long enough for me to click the link? At the moment when I try to move to the tooltip to click the link it just disappear and either shows the tooltip for the next cell in the heatmap or goes away since I am outside the cell.

Probably something can be done with css transitions/delays for the apexcharts tooltips but can't figure it out.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2kmgpc5w/1/

BR,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested in this.

I was unable to make a tooltip clickable in apexcharts so I diabled tooltips in apexcharts and introduced a bootstrap popover instead like this that works similar to a tooltip.

```
$('.apexcharts-heatmap-rect').popover({
    trigger: "manual",
    placement: "top",
    container: "body",
    html: true,
    animation: false,
    content: function () {
        return "<p><b>Verdict: </b>Fail</p><p><b>Issues</b><br><a href=\"https://mylink.com\">Issue 1</a><br><a href=\"https://mylink.com\">Issue 2</a></p><p><b>Comments</b><br>Issue 1 is critical making this test area fail</p>";
    }
  })
  .on("mouseenter", function() {
    var _this = this;
    console.log("enter this");
    console.log(this);
    console.log($(this).attr("val"));
    $(this).popover("show");
    $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function() {
    
     console.log("leave popover");
      $(_this).popover('hide');
    });
  }).on("mouseleave", function() {
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
     console.log("leave cell");
      if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
        $(_this).popover("hide");
      }
    }, 20);
  });
});
```

Comment: Such as it's more than 2 days, you can accept your owner answer !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround that I came up with. It's tracking the mouse when it enteres the chart, and are updating the tooltip position every time you hover over a new column.

Not a very nice solution but got the job done for me.

```
import React, { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { ApexChart, getTheme} from '@myLib';
import { useStore } from '@store/Store';
import { APP_NAME } from '@constants';
import PeriodicOverviewTooltip from '@components/Charts/PeriodicOverviewChart/PeriodicOverviewTooltip';

const getOptions = (categories, theme, setShowTooltip, setPositions) => {
  const {
    palette: {
      mode,
      charts: { background, rowColors, twoColorsContrast }
    }
  } = theme;
  return {
    chart: {
      id: 'periodic-overview-chart',
      type: 'line',
      height: 350,
      background: background,
      zoom: {
        enabled: false
      },
      toolbar: {
        show: false
      },
      events: {
        mouseMove: function (event) {
          let left = event.pageX;
          if (left >= window.innerWidth - 400) {
            left = window.innerWidth - 400;
          }
          setPositions({ left: left, top: event.pageY });
        }
      }
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    stroke: {
      width: [2]
    },
    colors: twoColorsContrast,
    theme: {
      mode: mode
    },
    xaxis: {
      categories: categories,
      title: {
        text: '',
        style: {
          fontFamily: ['Poppins', 'Roboto', 'helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif'].join(',')
        }
      }
    },
    yaxis: [
      {
        title: {
          text: 'MWh',
          offsetY: -215,
          offsetX: 20,
          rotate: 0,
          style: {
            fontFamily: ['Roboto', 'helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif'].join(','),
            fontSize: '12px',
            fontWeight: 100
          }
        },
        decimalsInFloat: 0,
        labels: {
          style: {
            fontFamily: ['Roboto', 'helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif'].join(',')
          }
        }
      },
      {
        opposite: true,
        title: {
          text: 'MWh',
          offsetY: -215,
          offsetX: -20,
          rotate: 0,
          style: {
            fontFamily: ['Roboto', 'helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif'].join(','),
            fontSize: '12px',
            fontWeight: 100
          }
        },
        decimalsInFloat: 0,
        labels: {
          style: {
            fontFamily: ['Roboto', 'helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif'].join(',')
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    fill: {
      opacity: 1
    },
    grid: {
      row: {
        colors: rowColors,
        opacity: 0.5
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        columnWidth: '50%',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      custom: function ({ dataPointIndex }) {
        setShowTooltip(dataPointIndex);
        return `<div id='my-tooltip' style="visibility: hidden"></div>`;
      }
    },
    noData: {
      text: 'There is no data to display'
    }
  };
};

function PeriodicOverviewChart({ globalUnitDisplay }) {
  const [series, setSeries] = useState([
    {
      name: 'Consumption',
      type: 'column',
      data: [13, 46, 44, 59, 59, 50, 55, 57, 56, 50, 52, 51, 50, 48]
    },
    {
      name: 'Accumulated',
      type: 'line',
      data: [125, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750]
    }
  ]);
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([
    '7 Aug 23',
    '8 Aug 23',
    '9 Aug 23',
    '10 Aug 23',
    '11 Aug 23',
    '12 Aug 23',
    '13 Aug 23',
    '14 Aug 23',
    '15 Aug 23',
    '16 Aug 23',
    '17 Aug 23',
    '18 Aug 23',
    '19 Aug 23',
    '20 Aug 23'
  ]);
  const [showTooltip, setShowTooltip] = useState(null);
  const [positions, setPositions] = useState({ left: 0, top: 0 });
  const [tempPositions, setTempPositions] = useState({ left: 0, top: 0 });
  const {
    state: { user, themeMode }
  } = useStore();

  useEffect(() => {
    let chart = document.getElementById('apexchartsperiodic-overview-chart');
    chart.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      let tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip-display');
      if (!tooltip.matches(':hover')) {
        setShowTooltip(null);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let chart = document.getElementById('apexchartsperiodic-overview-chart');
    let pos = chart.getBoundingClientRect();
    let maxHeight = pos.bottom + pos.height - 200;
    if (tempPositions.top > maxHeight) {
      setPositions({ ...tempPositions, ...{ top: maxHeight } });
    } else {
      setPositions(tempPositions);
    }
  }, [showTooltip]);

  const options = useMemo(() => {
    const theme = getTheme(themeMode ? 'dark' : 'light', APP_NAME);
    return getOptions(categories, theme, setShowTooltip, setTempPositions);
  }, [themeMode, categories]);

  return (
    <>
      {showTooltip !== null && (
        <PeriodicOverviewTooltip column={showTooltip} positions={positions} />
      )}
      <ApexChart
        loading={false}
        height={480}
        options={options || {}}
        type={'line'}
        data={series}></ApexChart>
    </>
  );
}

export default PeriodicOverviewChart;

function PeriodicOverviewTooltip({ positions, column }) {
  return (
    <div
      id={'tooltip-display'}
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        width: 'fit-content',
        zIndex: 200,
        top: `${positions.top}px`,
        left: `${positions.left}px`
      }}>...content...</div>
    

export default PeriodicOverviewTooltip;
```